# Is cardinal exponentiation strictly monotone in the exponent?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal, does $2^\kappa<2^{\kappa^+}$ always hold? It clearly holds if one assumes generalized continuum hypothesis, but does it also hold if one assumes otherwise?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this is independent of ZFC.

Comment: when $\kappa=\aleph_0$ this statement is the negation of Luzin's hypothesis

Comment: [Possible relevant](https://mathoverflow.net/a/6594/48041)

Answer (score 2):

This is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. It consistently holds, because it holds under $\mathsf{GCH}$, and it consistently doesn't hold, because a two step iteration of Cohen forcing over a model of $\mathsf{GCH}$ can be used to force $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$.

Comment: A two-step iteration of Cohen forcing? How?

Comment: @Jonathan First you force with $\mathrm{Fn}(\kappa\times\omega_1,2)$, then with $\mathrm{Fn}(\kappa\times\omega,2)$, where $\kappa$ is the result you want for both exponentiations

Comment: The two forcings are equivalent and one already suffices (of course assuming $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa) > \omega_1$). I would call this the forcing adding $\kappa$ many Cohen reals or the finite support iteration of Cohen forcing. In any case two-step iteration is confusing to me, since even what you propose is just product forcing.